# Enhance Resilience of Local Storage in Hybrid App

Tags: ios, sqlite, hybrid-mobile-app, indexeddb

I have developed a hybrid mobile app that has been running on IOS, Android and Chrome reasonably well for over 5 years. My app uses an indexedDB database to maintain the state of the app and save it between restarts, however there are some cases where IOS can clear the indexedDB particularly if the client device is running low on memory.

I would like some help on how to maintain a parallel copy of the indexedDB using the native SQL database on the IOS device, in order to increase the resilience of my app, based on the hopeful expectation that IOS will not arbitrarily decide to clear an internal SQL database belonging to the app.

I understand how to communicate in both directions between Objective C and Javascript but I have not the foggiest idea in Objective C how to:

1. Create a SQL database in the app file system
2. Choose where to place the SQL database in the app file system
3. How to write a new key value pair to the database
4. Overwrite an existing key value pair in the database
5. Read back all key value pairs from the database (I expect there could be up to 1000 of these in practice) and pass these efficiently back to the javascript code.
6. Clear the database and start again.

Any pointers to useful resources on how to achieve this or better still coded examples would be most appreciated.

I would just like to add that I am not using Cordova or any other similar app development environment, so please do not suggest a SQLite plugin that is part of a bigger environment. I have got to where I am with a bespoke coding approach and I would like to keep it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I have explored the idea of paralleling up each indexedDB save with a write to a file in the IOS App Documents Folder with the hope that this is less likely to be wiped than the Caches Folder.

Following each indexedDB setItem with a key-value-pair I pass a request to the objective-C IOS app code to create a text file in a sub folder created with the App Documents Folder, with the name 'key'.txt and the contents set to value.

Following each indexedDB removeItem, I pass a request to the objective-C IOS app code to delete the corresponding text file 'key'.txt.

Following each indexedDB clearAll, I delete the entire sub folder created above.

Now when the app starts up and discovers an empty localForage database, I pass a request to the objective-C IOS app code to test if the sub-folder with key-items is there or not.

If it is not, then this is a fresh install of the app and continue as normal for such a case.

if it is, then this is a case of the indexedDB database having been deleted.

In such case, I request the objective-C IOS app code to return the set of keys, by examining the contents of the folder created above and stripping off the .txt bit and in the case of the IOS Simulator ignoring the DS_Store file.

One by one I then request the contents of each key file and load them back into the previously empty localForage database and when this has been done I can continue as if it had not been deleted.

I found that it is necessary to use a zero duration timeout in the javascript before requesting each value to prevent call stack exceeded errors when restoring large databases.

This approach seems to work and I can test this any time by using the Safari Developer Resources tab actions to clear the database and then manually restarting the app. Using the same tab you can watch the indexedDB database being repopulated.

Due to the size of my database, I actually created a set of sub folders of different types of key, so that I could choose the order in which the database items were restored, especially as my app is often brought back to life in the background following a significant location change and in such cases there is an imposed maximum time limit on how long the app is given to do such a recovery. This refinement is of course optional and only needed for large databases.

The following notes are for anyone who wants to try this approach and assumes using Objective C in XCode 10.1

1. Use NSHomeDirectory() and stringByAppendingPathComponent @"Documents" to get the Documents folder.
2. Use stringByAppendingPathComponent to create a sub folder path for the keys sub folder.
3. Use fileExistsAtPath to check whether the keys sub folder exists already
4. Use createDirectoryAtPath if it does not.
5. When saving or changing items in indexedDB use the stringByAppendingPathComponent to create the key file name path e.g. Base.txt for a key of 'Base'.
6. Use fileHandleforWritingAtPath to get the fileHandle for a file
7. if fileHandle does not exist then need to create it using writeToFile to create the 'key' file
8. if fileHandle does exist then truncateFileAtOffseyt:0 (important) to clear it and then use writeData to create a new version of the 'key' file.
9. In both of the above specify UTF8 encoding.
10. When removing items from indexedDB do the same to get the key file path and then use removeItemAtPath.
11. The device can be cleared by removing the entire sub folder using removeItemAtPath.
12. The restore process uses contentsOfDirectoryAtPath to read the set of keys in the sub folder.
13. The restore process for each item uses stringWithContentsOfFile to read data files and return the contents enclosed in quotes using a call to stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

Hope this helps.